# Regex doesn't match with the lines in txt file

Tags: regex, bash

I'm reading the lines from a text file and check if it matches with the regex that I've created or not.

But it always says that your regex didn't match but the regex tool shows that it matches with my regular explanation.

```
while read line
do
name=$line
BRANCH_REGEX="\d{10}\-[^_]*\_\d{13}"
if [[ $name =~ $BRANCH_REGEX ]];
then
    echo "BRANCH '$name' matches BRANCH_REGEX '$BRANCH_REGEX'"
else
    echo "BRANCH '$name' DOES NOT MATCH BRANCH_REGEX '$BRANCH_REGEX'"
fi
done < names.txt
```

names.txt includes lines for example :

```
9000999484-suchocka_1416578464908
9000989944-schubertk_1416582641605
9001026342-extbeerfelde_1416586904787
9000687045-sturmjo_1416573131629
9001059401-extburghartswieser_1416405627982
9000806302-PDPUPDATE_1357830207068
9000658783-PDPUPDATE_1360445087963
```

Comment: Your regex starts with `/`, but none of your lines contains `/` . . .

Comment: I deleted the first '/' but again it won't match...

Comment: Cool. So, now you just need to figure out the other problems with your regex. ("My code doesn't work" isn't a good StackOverflow question. Surely you can play around and figure out which part is the problem?)

Comment: The problem was about bash configuration, i think it is not a question like 'my code isn't work'.

Comment: What I'm saying is, you posted a relatively large block of code. It is inconceivable that you *couldn't* narrow down your problem more precisely; instead, it must be that you *chose not to* do so, figuring that you could outsource your debugging to StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your regex to:

```
BRANCH_REGEX="[0-9]{10}-[^_]*_[0-9]{13}"
```

Or else:

```
BRANCH_REGEX="[[:digit:]]{10}-[^_]*_[[:digit:]]{13}"
```

As **BASH regex doesn't support `\d` property**. There is no need to escape hyphens.

Answer (score 2):

```
BRANCH_REGEX="/\d{10}\-[^_]*\_\d{13}"
              ↑
```

Remove the leading `/`, none of your lines begin with it.

Also note that `_` doesn't need to be escaped, you can write `_` instead of `\_`.